# Why this 'collapse' div isn't closing once opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have a `div` element close and open using Twitter Bootstraps collapse feature, and for some reason, despite opening just fine it will not close.

I've tried to trigger it via Javascript and data attributes and neither has worked. Adding width and/or height properties to the CSS of it also changes nothing. I can reset it via `removeClass('in');`, but that is sudden and isn't preferable.

*Javascript:*

```
// Hide/show achievement reward on mouse enter/leave
$(".achievement").each(function (i) {
    var reward = $(this).find(".reward");
    $(this).mouseenter(function () { reward.collapse('toggle'); });
    $(this).mouseleave(function () { reward.collapse('toggle'); });
});
```

*HTML:*

```
<div class="achievement collapse" title="..."><div class="title">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span> A Step Forward</div>
    <span class="description">Make one dollar.</span>
    <div class="reward collapse">+1 Stock</div></div> <!-- This element is what has the problem -->
```

*CSS:*

```
.reward {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 110%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(0,170,0,1);
}
```

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ycxuxbq5/1/

Comment: though I think using `show/hide` will be safer - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ycxuxbq5/4/

Comment: I found out why it was broken, and once more feel like an idiot. Also, @Arun - I do use `show` and `hide`, using `toggle` was just temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at my Javascript a little more after seeing my code worked in JSFiddle, I found this about 4 lines up:

```
$(".achievement").on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }); // So that achievements don't disappear after appearing
```

Apparently this also was affecting child elements because commenting this out fixed the issue.